# Why did my stats reset to 0?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops

I've had 5 days worth of gameplay last night, and all diamond guns. I come online today, and it's like I've just started the game for the first time.

I've never boosted, used glitches or any cheats, and I'm pretty pissed about the fact that I have to start from the beginning again.

Does anyone have any idea why this might have happened? I've had pretty decent K/D Ratios the past few days, sometimes up to 40+ kills and only 1 death, could this be why?

Comment: Have you been playing on any glitched servers?  That could be the cause of it.  40:1 K:D ratio sounds a little too good to be true.

Comment: Have you contacted their support or xbl for this reset?  Or do you have other friends you played with that their stats were reset as well?

Comment: Simple question, are you somehow logged out of your xbl account?

Answer (score 2):

It could be a simple glitch in your account info on the Black Ops 2 server, try restarting your console, deleting your online save file (back it up first on a USB and such first) and reconnecting to download it again. I have had it happen before in many games (Call of duty 4 and Halo Reach), it happens,normally after a restart or a few hours it restores itself. If nothing seems to work, try contacting Xbox live support.